# Find $m$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{\sin k}{k}-\csc(\frac{1}{2})\frac{3}{m}\gt 0$

Tags: calculus, summation

> Use a calculator to find an integer $m$ such that $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{\sin k}{k}-\csc\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{3}{m}\gt0$$

Is there a calculator online that I can plug this into?

Comment: On Windows you can use `calc.exe` :)

Comment: If you have access to a spread sheet (e.g., Microsoft Excel), you can very quickly generate a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yvgopjemjn) for this type of exercise.